# Can my variable data be read easily from a different app?

Tags: .net, variables, memory

I'm pretty sure StackOverflow is the best place to ask this but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have a .Net application that stores encrypted credit card numbers into an sql database, but I have to un-encrypt them temporarily to run a transaction. My question is, should I be concerned about someone being able to read my variable data from a third party program and retrieve the card data? How easy would it be for someone to extract the info from the memory my variable is storing its data in?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: If someone do this, he hacked .Net not your application.Clearly .Net encrypted values in ram itself.

Comment: @SamanGholami Are you saying .Net framework stores data encrypted when I assign a value to a variable, then un-encrypts it when I access the variable data?

Comment: If you ask how easy then here is the [answer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the data - you are probably OK.

Comment: Between your answer and the comment from @SriramSakthivel, I was able to secure the variable and verify the data could not be read. Thank you.